# Passing parameter cannot be edited

Tags: c, parameters

Why passing parameters couldn't be changed.
I have some function

```
void read_errorlog (int success, char *names, int empty) {
```

that is called from another, where

```
  const char *names[2] = {"errorlog.txt","errorlog1.txt"}
  int empty = 0;
  int counter = 0;
  int success = 0;
```

all variables are initialized. 
Inside of `void read_errorlog` neither `int success`, not `int empty` change there values.
I do it like `empty = 0;`
i was calling the function with `read_errorlog (one, two, three)`. I got now, that i have to pass addresses of int variables. Thank you.

Comment: Please write more accurte example code, because honestly I don't have idea what's the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the difference of call by value (what you are doing) and "call by reference" (what you should do).

When you call the function `read_errorlog`, the arguments that are passed are in reality copies of the variables that you give as arguments. So, when you do `empty=0` inside the function, you change the value of the copy, but not of the original variable.

For "calling by reference", you need to pass a pointer to `empty` and a pointer to `success` instead of their values. This can be done as follows:

```
void read_errorlog (int* success, char *names, int* empty) {
    *empty = 0;
    *success = 1;
}

read_errorlog(&success, names, &empty);
```

Comment: You should place the *calling by reference* into quotes as it's a simulated *pass by reference*, as in C there is only pass by value.

Comment: @alk- can you please give some more detail about "in C there is only pass by value." ?